# Unable to get cookies for flutter iOS webview

Tags: cookies, webview, dart, flutter, wkwebview

I am fetching cookies from a login page of a website using flutter webview inside my stateful widget. So after the user logins, and the url changes the cookies will be fetched. Right now I am unable to fetch cookies when my app is in iOS. By default in android, chrome webview is launched, while in iOS the wkwebview or safari webview is launched i think.

I am using the flutter inappbrowser plugin which has cookie manager built in. I tried changing the user agent but still same issue.

**Plugin:**

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_inappbrowser

I am using the same codes and i can fetch cookies in Android but not in iOS

```
import 'package:flutter_inappbrowser/flutter_inappbrowser.dart';

MyInAppBrowser inAppBrowser = new MyInAppBrowser();  

class MainScreen extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    _openWebView();
  }

  _openWebView() async{
     await inAppBrowser.open(url: "https://*****some 
      website*****/logon.php", options: {
      "javaScriptEnabled":true,
      "clearCache":true,
      "useShouldOverrideUrlLoading": true,
      "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77",
    });
  }
}

class MyInAppBrowser extends InAppBrowser {

   @override
   void onBrowserCreated() async {
      print("\n\nBrowser Ready!\n\n");
   }

   @override
   void onLoadStart(String url) async {
      CookieManager.getCookies(url).then((val) {
        debugPrint("COOKIEMANAGER: " + val.toString());
     });
   }

   @override
   void shouldOverrideUrlLoading(String url) {
      CookieManager.getCookies(url).then((val) {
        debugPrint("COOKIEMANAGER: " + val.toString());
      });

   }

   @override
   void onLoadError(String url, int code, String message) {
      print("\n\nCan't load $url.. Error: $message\n\n");
    }

    @override
    void onExit() {
        print("\n\nBrowser closed!\n\n");
    }

}
```

I should be able to get cookies info such as userid, sessionhash etc which is shown on Android

Comment: Solved this by using flutter_webview plugin instead. I have to add native codes to iOS and android, and call the methods from flutter.

Comment: can you please share the sample code what native code added and how are you calling in flutter dart to solve above mentioned issue.

Comment: Sure, but i have to edit my question as its using a different package. You can read this documentation on how to call native codes. 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels
You need to know objective-c (for this particular package) and java to inject native codes in ios/android and use Cookiemanager/NSHTTPCookieStorage for it's respective platform.

Comment: @FadhliS could you please share native code (at least on iOS) to get these cookies values?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that you're using (flutter_inappbrowser) seems to be outdated and has been discontinued. I suggest using [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/) as it has support for this feature and has just been recently out of developer preview.

To fetch cookies using `webview_flutter`, you can call `WebViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');`. The method `evaluateJavascript` is used to evaluate the JavaScript expression ['document.cookie'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) of the page and returns a String value. You can check the [sample in this page](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example) to try it out.

Comment: We can't use javascript to fetch cookies that contain 'http only' to true